# How to flash messages from inside promises in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash-message

How can we flash messages in node.js from inside promises? I used the library connect-flash https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash.

The following code doesn't work:

```
Patient.findOne({
    hospitalNumber
}).then((patient) => {
    if (_.isEmpty(patient)) {
        throw Error('Patient does not exist');
    }
    res.status(200).render('patientPage');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    req.flash('error_msg', "Something went wrong.");
    res.redirect(400, '/app');
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "flash messages"?

Comment: @Jorius I mean using a library for flashing messages https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash

Comment: The own connect-flash you posted has an example of how to provide the flash messages to the renderer: res.render('index', { messages: req.flash('info') });

Comment: @flaviodesousa, i would also need to show flash after redirect :)

Comment: Please be more specific that "*doesn't work*". Also, using a 400 status for a redirect is a horrible idea?!

Answer (score 0):

well, according to the library docs:

`req.flash('blah')`

your code has `res.flash`

`req` ==! `res`

:)

I hope it helps you!

Comment: my mistake in the post, I used req object in the actual code.

Comment: no worries, thats the maximum I could help as I'm not familiar with this library

Answer (score 0):

`connect-flash` is just a kind of store for messages. You still need to provide them to the render and *render* them yourself.

So add them to the render call...

```
res.redirect(400/*?*/, '/app', { messages: req.flash('error_msg') });
```

...and place them on your template (here assuming you use pug):

```
p= messages
```

It is worth mentioning that `flash()` returns an **array** of messages, *even when you flash only once*. So, to have better control you may use something like:

```
each message in messages
    p= message
```

Finally there is no special handling of flashes within promises. Everything you flash will be available to the renderer. So you could change your code to:

```
Patient.findOne({
    hospitalNumber
}).then((patient) => {
    if (_.isEmpty(patient)) {
        req.flash('error', 'Patient does not exist');
        throw Error('Patient does not exist');
    }
    res.status(200).render('patientPage');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect(400, '/app', { errors: req.flash('error') });
});
```

or, better yet (but without flash, note `error` instead of `errors`):

```
Patient.findOne({
    hospitalNumber
}).then((patient) => {
    if (_.isEmpty(patient)) {
        throw Error('Patient does not exist');
    }
    res.status(200).render('patientPage');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect(400, '/app', { error: err.message });
});
```

Comment: "didn't work" is not helpful either. What did happen? What did you get? What was the output?